# Animate growing div then animate child element

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I'm currently trying to `animate` a growing `<div>` but I don't want the content to look like it is growing along with it. The content should remain invisible while the `<div>` is animating and once it's fully grown I'd like for the content to become visible (by changing the opacity of the `<a>` in that `<div>`).

This is the code for the `<div>` animation:

```css
@keyframes menu {
  0% {
    background-color: white;
    right: -25px;
    top: -25px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
  }
  25%{
    right: -50px;
    top: -50px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
  }
  50% {
    right: -50px;
    top: -50px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 100px;
  }
  75%{
    right:-50px;
    top:-50px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 100px;
  }
  80%{
    right:-50px;
    top:-50px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 300px;
  }
  100%{
    right:-150px;
    top:-150px;
    width: 450px;
    height: 450px;
    border-radius: 600px;
  }
}
```

It's basically a menu that starts in the corner and grows until the full screen is covered (mobile). I've tried adding `a{ opacity: 1 };` but I guess it doesn't work like that.

Comment: Soo if i get it correctly you want a div to animate to a certain size and then show the content?

Comment: "i don't want you to see that".... then i would change the code/content in a way so everyone can see it, contribute the rest of your code and let us help you.

Comment: You mean something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/1m2fggmx/)?

Comment: @Keyboardninja Yes, exactly

Comment: @Harry I don't think it's working, but I see what you're trying to do. Lemme try in my code

Comment: @Greg: Yeah, it was because there was no `background-color` by default on the element in my original code. I've changed it and posted as answer. Check if it helps :) The idea will basically be the same.

Comment: Close voters, the question was a bit unclear initially but OP had already clarified what they were looking for and the question is no longer unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the anchor text (within the `div`) to be visible only after the animation on the parent `div` is fully complete then add another `animation` to the `a`, animate the `opacity` from 0 to 1 after a delay which is equal to the `animation-duration` of the parent.

```css
div {
  background-color: black;
  line-height: 450px;
  text-align: center;
  animation: menu 4s linear forwards;
}
a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  animation: display 1s linear 4s backwards;
}
@keyframes menu {
  0% {
    background-color: white;
    right: -25px;
    top: -25px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
  }
  25% {
    right: -50px;
    top: -50px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
  }
  50% {
    right: -50px;
    top: -50px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 100px;
  }
  75% {
    right: -50px;
    top: -50px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 100px;
  }
  80% {
    right: -50px;
    top: -50px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 300px;
  }
  100% {
    right: -150px;
    top: -150px;
    width: 450px;
    height: 450px;
    border-radius: 600px;
  }
}
@keyframes display {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href='#'>Some Menu Link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a little jQuery to do that. Using a callback you can call `opacity 1` on `a` after the `div` is complete grown.

```
  $( ".yourdiv" ).animate({
    width: "450"
    height: "450"
  }, 5000, function() {
    //callback will cause the a to change its opacity only when the above function is complete
    $('.yourdiv a').css('opacity') = '1';
  });
```